# Materialize css 1.0 nested dropdown

Tags: css, materialize

I have found a nested dropdown example for Materialize 0.98 but it's not working for Materialize 1.00. How would I port it over?

Working example with v0.98 - 
https://gist.github.com/the0neyouseek/f1a92b9b8f8962a372c23ef415c63144

I tried to follow the upgrade guide but couldn't get it to work.

```
Dropdown
Removed gutter option
Removed stopPropagation option
Call plugin on .dropdown-content instead of .dropdown-button
Change attribute data-activates to data-target
Rename classes .dropdown-button to .dropdown-trigger
Rename option belowOrigin to coverTrigger
Removed automatic initialization, initialize it manually as shown in documentation
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `data-activates` attribute with `data-target`.

```
<a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1' data-beloworigin="true">Nested DropDown</a>

<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content dropdown-nested'>
    <li><a class='dropdown-button' href='#' data-target='dropdown2' data-hover="hover" data-alignment="left">one<span class="right-triangle">&#9656;</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id='dropdown2' class='dropdown-content dropdown-nested'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a class='dropdown-button' href="#" data-target="dropdown3" data-hover="hover" data-alignment="left">two<span class="right-triangle">&#9656;</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id='dropdown3' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">six</a></li>
</ul>
```

Materialize changed this attribute in version 1.0 .

Have a look at [Materialize Dropdown Doc](https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```css
.dropdown-content > li {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content li .dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/FOOGLES/pen/LYYdQeK i hope this help you or other people with the same problem.

nested dropdown its not supported in mat v1 so we need to do some tricks, you need to activate the nested dropdowns with hover, so in matv1 you have to use {
hover: true } in the dropdown selector with Jquery,later with some CSS you make the second and third dropdown take position to the right with left:-100%; or left:100%; if you want the dropdown take left position, i comment the three common options in the CSS.

HTML:

```
    <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1' >Menu</a>

    <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content dropdown-nested'>

        <li><a href="#!">uno</a></li>
        <li><a class='dropdown-trigger sub' href='#' data-target='dropdown2' >uno*</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">uno</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id='dropdown2' class='dropdown-content dropdown-nested'>
        <li><a href="#!">dos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">dos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">dos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">dos</a></li>
        <li><a class='dropdown-trigger sub' href="#" data-target="dropdown3" >dos*</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id='dropdown3' class='dropdown-content'>
        <li><a href="#!">tres</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">tres</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">tres</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">tres</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
    .dropdown-nested {
        overflow-y: visible;
    }
    .dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
       /* left: 100%;*/ /*drop hacia la izquierda*/
       left: -100%; /*drop hacia la derecha*/
       /* left: auto;*/ /*drop hacia el centro*/
    }
    .container {
        background: #eee;
        padding: 200px 100px;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }
```

`$('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
  $('.sub').dropdown(
  {
    hover:true
  }`

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: i add some explanation, sorry. its my first contribution.

Comment: Your solution seems to work properly, but when trying to move the css to a dedicated stylesheet, the overflow-y doesn't work, any idea why ? Here's a Live Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/ThibaudMZN/nrqbs0mv/35/